# How do I best combine directional movements (up and left, up and right...) when moving objects?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, easeljs

I am using EaselJS in Javascript and I am using the `keydown` and `keyup` events to catch keyboard input (see below):

```
/*Connecting keydown input to keyPressed handler*/
this.document.onkeydown = keyPressed;
/*Connecting key up event to keyUp handler*/
this.document.onkeyup = keyUp;
```

And I have the following code to capture when up down, left and/or right are pressed, and to react to them temporarily. The movement is very shabby now, and I'm still trying to refine it. For me to be able to move my object correctly, I should be able to catch angle changes (left/right) and acceleration (forward) simulataneously.

Here is the keyDown code I have currently:

```
    /*Keyboard input handlers - keydown and keyup*/
    function keyPressed(event){
        if(!event){ var event = window.event; }
        switch(event.keyCode){
            case KEYCODE_LEFT: 
                console.log("left held");
                ellip.x -= 5;
                break;
            case KEYCODE_RIGHT: 
                console.log("right held");
                ellip.x += 5; 
                break;
            case KEYCODE_UP: 
                console.log("up held");
                ellip.y -= 5;
                break;
            case KEYCODE_DOWN: 
                console.log("down held");
                ellip.y += 5;
                break;          
        }
    }
```

Now notice in the console that hitting two of the arrow buttons does not yield combinations of messages (eg. `up held` and `right held`)

How do I go about dealing (or listening) to multiple events?

[Here is a Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/AyrJH/) use the up, down, left and right arrows to move the red blotch around.

Comment: Is `easeljs` actually relevant to your question?

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to match key downs to key ups. If you get another key down before you get a key up from the last key down, then two keys are being held down. Apart from shift, ctrl, etc, there's no way to test if a key is currently held down that you'd need to see if up *and* left are both being held.

Comment: Also, your fiddle seems to behave pretty well anyway (on Chrome). If you hit two arrow keys at once, it *usually* appears as one smooth diagonal movement.

Comment: @MattBurland Well I am using EaselJS and I think people familiar with that library have probably dealt with this issue at some point. The diagonal comment is confusing, I am using Chrome as well and haven't been able to make the blob move like that.

Comment: Ok - I was just looking at a press and release. It really doesn't work well for a repeat (i.e. holding the keys down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to handle this would be to capture which keys are down in your keyDown code and then do the movement itself in the handleTick function. You'll need to look at keyUp too so you know when the key is no longer down:

```
/*Keyboard input handlers - keydown and keyup*/
var left,
    right,
    up,
    down;

function keyPressed(event){
    if(!event){ var event = window.event; }
    switch(event.keyCode){
        case KEYCODE_LEFT: 
            console.log("left held");
            left = true;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_RIGHT: 
            console.log("right held");
            right = true; 
            break;
        case KEYCODE_UP: 
            console.log("up held");
            up = true;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_DOWN: 
            console.log("down held");
            down = true;
            break;          
    }
}

function keyReleased(event){
    if(!event){ var event = window.event; }
    switch(event.keyCode){
        case KEYCODE_LEFT: 
            console.log("left released");
            left = false;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_RIGHT: 
            console.log("right released");
            right = false; 
            break;
        case KEYCODE_UP: 
            console.log("up released");
            up = false;
            break;
        case KEYCODE_DOWN: 
            console.log("down released");
            down = false;
            break;          
    }
}

function handleTick(event){
    /*Scaling down the image*/
    ellip.scaleX = 0.10;
    ellip.scaleY = 0.10;

    if(left) {
        ellip.x -= 5;
    } else if(right) {
        ellip.x += 5;
    }

    if(up) {
        ellip.y -= 5;
    } else if(down) {
        ellip.y += 5;
    }

    if (ellip.x > stage.canvas.width) { 
        ellip.x = stage.canvas.width; 
    }   
    stage.update();
}
```

EDIT: forked fiddle with this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/t2M82/

Comment: Great concise explanation, and thank you for the Fiddle usage.